# opencv-python,image .TypeError: disparity data type = 17 is not supported

Tags: 3d, open3d

I'm using opencv to do 3D reconstruction, but I can't solve this problem, I hope someone who can understand this problem can help me.the problem is this
File "C:\Users\1\PycharmProjects\SGMsanweichongjian\SGM.py", line 301, in 
points_3d = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(pointcloud, Q)
TypeError: disparity data type = 17 is not supported.
[enter image description here]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd03g.p[[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd03g.p%5B%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsSVc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSxBx.png)ng)